# How to properly unit test directives with DOM manipulation?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, dom, angularjs-directive

Before asking my real question, I have a different one... Does it make sense to **unit test** DOM manipulation in Angular directives?

For instance, here's my complete linking function:

```
function linkFn(scope, element) {
    var ribbon = element[0];
    var nav = ribbon.children[0];

    scope.ctrl.ribbonItemClick = function (index) {
        var itemOffsetLeft;
        var itemOffsetRight;
        var item;

        if (scope.ctrl.model.selectedIndex === index) {
            return;
        }

        scope.ctrl.model.selectedIndex = index;

        item = nav.querySelectorAll('.item')[index];

        itemOffsetLeft = item.offsetLeft - ribbon.offsetLeft;
        itemOffsetRight = itemOffsetLeft + item.clientWidth;

        if (itemOffsetLeft < nav.scrollLeft) {
            nav.scrollLeft = itemOffsetLeft - MAGIC_PADDING;
        }

        if(itemOffsetRight > nav.clientWidth + nav.scrollLeft) {
            nav.scrollLeft = itemOffsetRight - nav.clientWidth + MAGIC_PADDING;
        }

        this.itemClick({
            item: scope.ctrl.model.items[index],
            index: index
        });

        $location.path(scope.ctrl.model.items[index].href);
    };

    $timeout(function $timeout() {
        var item = nav.querySelector('.item.selected');
        nav.scrollLeft = item.offsetLeft - ribbon.offsetLeft - MAGIC_PADDING;
    });
}
```

This is for a scrollable tabbed component and I have no idea how to test the 3 instances of `nav.scrollLeft = x`.

The first two `if` statements happen when an item - which is only partially visible - is clicked. The left/right (each `if`) item will be snapped to the left/right border of the component.

The third one, is to place the selected item in view if it's not visible when the component is loaded.

How do I unit test this with Karma/Jasmine. does it even make sense to do it or should I do functional tests with Protractor instead?

Comment: That's a broad question and it might depends on personal preferences. As for me and my colleges in company we unit test controllers/services/factories to verify correct data manipulation and e2e to test if it looks properly

Comment: What about coverage? Do you just ignore it in these scenarios?

Answer (score 12):

When testing directives, look for things that set or return explicit values. These are generally easy to assert and it makes sense to unit test them with Jasmine and Karma.

Take a look at Angular's [tests for `ng-src`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ng/directive/ngSrcSpec.js). Here, they test that the directive works by asserting that the `src` attribute on the element gets set to the right values. It is explicit: either the `src` attribute has a specific value or it does not.

```
it('should not result empty string in img src', inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
  $rootScope.image = {};
  element = $compile('<img ng-src="{{image.url}}">')($rootScope);
  $rootScope.$digest();
  expect(element.attr('src')).not.toBe('');
  expect(element.attr('src')).toBe(undefined);
}));
```

The same with [ng-bind](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ng/directive/ngBindSpec.js). Here, they pass a string of HTML with to the $compiler and then assert that the return value has had its HTML populated with actual scope values. Again, it is explicit.

```
it('should set text', inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
  element = $compile('<div ng-bind="a"></div>')($rootScope);
  expect(element.text()).toEqual('');
  $rootScope.a = 'misko';
  $rootScope.$digest();
  expect(element.hasClass('ng-binding')).toEqual(true);
  expect(element.text()).toEqual('misko');
}));
```

When you get into more complicated scenarios like testing against viewport visibility or testing whether specific elements are positioned in the right places on the page, you could try to test that CSS and `style` attributes get set properly, but that gets fiddly real quick and is not recommended. At this point you should be looking at Protractor or a similar e2e testing tool.

Comment: We already have Protractor for e2e testing on the whole website, but I was just looking into unit testing that piece of code so I could achieve 100% test coverage. Protractor will help test that this directive is working properly but help achieve the unit tests coverage.

Answer (score 6):

I would 100% want to test all the paths of your directive even if it isn't the easiest thing. But there are approaches you can take to make this process simpler.

### Break Complicated Logic into Service

The first thing that stands out to me is the complicated piece of logic about setting the nav `scrollLeft`. Why not break this into a separate service that can be unit tested on its own?

```
app.factory('AutoNavScroller', function() {
  var MAGIC_PADDING;
  MAGIC_PADDING = 25;

  return function(extraOffsetLeft) {

    this.getScrollPosition = function(item, nav) {
      var itemOffsetLeft, itemOffsetRight;

      itemOffsetLeft = item.offsetLeft - extraOffsetLeft;
      itemOffsetRight = itemOffsetLeft + item.clientWidth;

      if ( !!nav && itemOffsetRight > nav.clientWidth + nav.scrollLeft) {

        return itemOffsetRight - nav.clientWidth + MAGIC_PADDING;


      } else {

        return itemOffsetLeft - MAGIC_PADDING;

      }
    };
  }
});
```

This makes it much easier to test all the paths and refactor (which you can see I was able to do above. The tests can be seen below:

```
describe('AutoNavScroller', function() {
  var AutoNavScroller;

  beforeEach(module('app'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_AutoNavScroller_) {
    AutoNavScroller = _AutoNavScroller_;
  }));

  describe('#getScrollPosition', function() {
    var scroller, item;

    function getScrollPosition(nav) {
      return scroller.getScrollPosition(item, nav);
    }

    beforeEach(function() {
      scroller = new AutoNavScroller(50);
      item = {
        offsetLeft: 100
      };
    })

    describe('with setting initial position', function() {
      it('gets the initial scroll position', function() {
        expect(getScrollPosition()).toEqual(25);
      });
    });

    describe('with item offset left of the nav scroll left', function() {
      it('gets the scroll position', function() {
        expect(getScrollPosition({
          scrollLeft: 100
        })).toEqual(25);
      });
    });

    describe('with item offset right of the nav width and scroll left', function() {
      beforeEach(function() {
        item.clientWidth = 300;
      });

      it('gets the scroll position', function() {
        expect(getScrollPosition({
          scrollLeft: 25,
          clientWidth: 50
        })).toEqual(325);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

### Test That Directive is Calling Service

Now that we've broken up our directive, we can just inject the service and make sure it is called correctly.

```
app.directive('ribbonNav', function(AutoNavScroller, $timeout) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element) {
      var navScroller;
      var ribbon = element[0];
      var nav = ribbon.children[0];

      // Assuming ribbon offsetLeft remains the same
      navScroller = new AutoNavScroller(ribbon.offsetLeft);

      scope.ctrl.ribbonItemClick = function (index) {

        if (scope.ctrl.model.selectedIndex === index) {
            return;
        }

        scope.ctrl.model.selectedIndex = index;

        item = nav.querySelectorAll('.item')[index];

        nav.scrollLeft = navScroller.getScrollLeft(item, nav);
        // ...rest of directive
      };

      $timeout(function $timeout() {
        var item = nav.querySelector('.item.selected');

        // Sets initial nav scroll left
        nav.scrollLeft = navScroller.getScrollLeft(item);
      });

    }
  }
});
```

The easiest way to make sure our directive keeps using the service, is to just spy on the methods that it will call and make sure they are receiving the correct parameters:

```
describe('ribbonNav', function() {
  var $compile, $el, $scope, AutoNavScroller;

  function createRibbonNav() {
    $el = $compile($el)($scope);
    angular.element(document)
    $scope.$digest();
    document.body.appendChild($el[0]);
  }

  beforeEach(module('app'));

  beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
    AutoNavScroller = jasmine.createSpy();
    AutoNavScroller.prototype.getScrollLeft = function(item, nav) {
      return !nav ? 50 : 100;
    };
    spyOn(AutoNavScroller.prototype, 'getScrollLeft').and.callThrough();

    $provide.provider('AutoNavScroller', function () {
      this.$get = function () {
        return AutoNavScroller;
      }
    });
  }));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, $rootScope) {
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $el = "<div id='ribbon_nav' ribbon-nav><div style='width:50px;overflow:scroll;float:left;'><div class='item selected' style='height:100px;width:200px;float:left;'>An Item</div><div class='item' style='height:100px;width:200px;float:left;'>An Item</div></div></div>";
    $scope = $rootScope.$new()
    $scope.ctrl = {
      model: {
        selectedIndex: 0
      }
    };
    createRibbonNav();
  }));

  afterEach(function() {
    document.getElementById('ribbon_nav').remove();
  });

  describe('on link', function() {
    it('calls AutoNavScroller with selected item', inject(function($timeout) {
      expect(AutoNavScroller).toHaveBeenCalledWith(0);
    }));

    it('calls AutoNavScroller with selected item', inject(function($timeout) {
      $timeout.flush();
      expect(AutoNavScroller.prototype.getScrollLeft)
        .toHaveBeenCalledWith($el[0].children[0].children[0]);
    }));

    it('sets the initial nav scrollLeft', inject(function($timeout) {
      $timeout.flush();
      expect($el[0].children[0].scrollLeft).toEqual(50);
    }));
  });

  describe('ribbonItemClick', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      $scope.ctrl.ribbonItemClick(1);
    });

    it('calls AutoNavScroller with item', inject(function($timeout) {
      expect(AutoNavScroller.prototype.getScrollLeft)
        .toHaveBeenCalledWith($el[0].children[0].children[1], $el[0].children[0]);
    }));

    it('sets the nav scrollLeft', function() {
      expect($el[0].children[0].scrollLeft).toEqual(100);
    });
  });
});
```

Now, obviously these specs can be refactored a 100 ways but you can see that a higher coverage is much easier to achieve once we started breaking out the complicated logic. There are some risks around mocking objects too much because it can make your tests brittle but I believe the tradeoff is worth it here. Plus I can definitely see that `AutoNavScroller` being generalized and reused elsewhere. That would not have been possible if the code existed in the directive before.

### Conclusion

Anyways, the reason why I believe Angular is great is the ability to test these directives and how they interact with the DOM. These jasmine specs can be run in any browser and will quickly surface inconsistencies or regressions.

Also, here is a plunkr so you can see all the moving pieces and experiment: http://plnkr.co/edit/wvj4TmmJtxTG0KW7v9rn?p=preview

Comment: No offense, but I completely disagree with such approach. I mean, create services for the sake of testing. I see that as compromising a simple and good solution for the sake of testing and I personally don't like that. Also, the service you created will most likely never be used by another directive or whatever, it's specific to this one directive. In a way, you're exposing an internal implementation detail to a service with a public API just for testing purposes, feels wrong to me. But I still appreciate your input. Thanks you.

Comment: Alright, fair enough, it really isn't just for testing sake but to modularize some complicated logic. I can definitely see the reason to leave it in since it isn't too bad though. I would still try to test all paths but instead of mocking, manually setting the elements attributes. Good luck.

Comment: I honestly don't see that bits of code as "complicated logic". I'm all for modularization but in this particular case I don't see the need since that logic is an internal implementation detail of *this ribbon* directive, and nothing else. I'll try that other approach, but not sure how I feel about it.